# How can I set env variables for a dockerfile at runtime in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift

I have a Jenkinsfile that builds a docker image and deploys that image to 4 environments. I would like environment variables in my docker image only for 2 of the 4 environments. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the `docker run -e` option to set an environment variable when you start a container.  It sounds like you have a more involved question than that, though; can you add a relevant fragment of your Jenkinsfile to the question to explain in a little more detail what trouble you’re running into?

Comment: I guess a better question would be if there is a way to get environment variables from openshift to dockerfile. Because we use an internal Jenkins library it is more complex than what our Jenkinsfile does. Just pushing an image to a docker artifactory. Then pulling that image and pushing to openshift.